# Extracting specific text from the end of a custom (text) log file with bash

Tags: awk

I only want the *most recent five numbers* (which are a the bottom of the file which might have hundreds of such groups)

```
{Previous entries would be above, perhaps hundreds of similar groups....}

[June 18, 2019, 12:37 pm Europe/Madrid +0200]
--------------------------------------------------

Added: 2
Modified: 3
Deleted: 1
Excluded: 2
Total Time: 5.09

[June 19, 2019, 12:37 pm Europe/Madrid +0200]
---------------------------------------------------

Added: 3
Modified: 0
Deleted: 2
Excluded: 1
Total Time: 6.18
```

How can I extract the numbers from this file? I have tried various approaches using sed, but especially grabbing only the last five values eludes me.

The output I am looking for is:

```
echo "<added>3</added>";
echo "<modified>0</modified>";
echo "<deleted>2</modified>";
echo "<excluded>1</excluded>";
echo "<total>6.18</total>";
```

I have been asked to specifically show what I tried, because the fact that I've provided in excess of 200 answers here for other people in my spare time, doesn't exclude me from being tested like a schoolboy, so here you are... this didn't work:

```
echo $file | awk -F'Added:' '{print $2}'
```

I hope that's proves useful.

Comment: To answer your last [deleted question/comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666301/extracting-values-from-a-custom-text-log-file-with-bash#comment99900786_56666301). Normally there is one downvote if you don't show how you tried to solve the problem. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I have mentioned I tried to use sed, do I really have to show all the lines I tried that didn't work? It's pedantic in the extreme no? Even for SO

Comment: @Cyrus - Edited to show I am not a timewaster despite my reasonable rep.

Comment: `the fact that I've provided in excess of 200 answers here for other people in my spare time` makes you no different from anyone else asking for help so it doesn't excuse you from posting a good question including input, output, and code and it doesn't mean that anyone reading your question can distinguish it from someone asking us to do their homework for them so without code YMMV with who's willing to write the code for you with no effort shown. @Cyrus was just giving you good advice on how to get answers, not being pedantic or testing you "like a schoolboy".

Comment: @Ed Morton I respect your opinion, but I don't agree. My, and your, reputation here is just that - literally reputation. Why does reputation count everywhere else in society except on SO? We all know the "sorts of questions" that the "show your work so far" rule pertains too, and there's no way my question, in which I had already mentioned a "sed" based approach needed to include lines of sed that hadn't worked. I knew it was the wrong approach, and I was asking for help... which thankfully I did receive.

Comment: Fair enough. Next time you have such a question you should definitely not show your attempt. Good luck.

Comment: @Ed Morten. That's a non sequitur. The next question I ask might well include the steps I have already taken - if they are relevant and helpful to the question, and not just an attempt to slavishly follow the rules to the benefit of no one.

Comment: No it's not a non sequitur. I said "Next time you have **such a question**" not "Next time you have any question". Obviously do whatever you like, all we can do is give advice on how best to get answers on this forum based on our experience using this forum but of course it's entirely up to you how you proceed given that advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and a regex:

```
tail -n 5 file | while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ (.*):\ (.*) ]]; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; done
```

Output:

```
Added 3
Modified 0
Deleted 2
Excluded 1
Total Time 6.18
```

Update:

```
tail -n 5 file | while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ([^\ ]*).*:\ (.*) ]]; echo "echo \"<${BASH_REMATCH[1],,}>${BASH_REMATCH[2]}</${BASH_REMATCH[1],,}>\""; done
```

Output:

```
echo "<added>3</added>"
echo "<modified>0</modified>"
echo "<deleted>2</deleted>"
echo "<excluded>1</excluded>"
echo "<total>6.18</total>"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will see if I can adapt it, since (pedantically) it's not the output I asked for.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but so far I have not managed to achieve my desired output I'm afraid

Comment: Try this: `echo "echo \"<${BASH_REMATCH[1]}>${BASH_REMATCH[2]}</${BASH_REMATCH[1]}>\""` The last line is not quite correct I just noticed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[: ]+' '
    NF { tags[++numTags]=tolower($1); vals[numTags]=$NF; next }
    { numTags=0 }
    END {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            printf "echo \"<%s>%s</%s>\";\n", tags[tagNr], vals[tagNr], tags[tagNr]
        }
    }
' file
echo "<added>3</added>";
echo "<modified>0</modified>";
echo "<deleted>2</deleted>";
echo "<excluded>1</excluded>";
echo "<total>6.18</total>";
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the input, I won't lie, I cannot follow a word of it! I won't ask for a laborious explanation, unless you think others would benefit, but I would appreciate hearing if you think this is better, worse, or "much the same" as the answer above. Is it simply a different approach for interest's sake?

Comment: Using awk is a better approach in general as it's more efficient (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219) but in this particular case that doesn't matter much since you're only reading 5 lines in the loop, and it's more portable as it'll work on with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box rather than being bash-only. There are other minor differences - mainly this is the right **general** approach but the tail | while loop is probably OK for your specific example.